# Page Navigation is not working with permalink structure

Tags: permalinks

I am displaying a list of employees using my custom plugin. My permalink structure is  `%category%%postname%/`

My page navigation was like `http://www.example.com/emp/?page=2`, and was working fine until now. But now it rewrites url like `http://www.example.com/emp/2/`.

I have read [Using Permalinks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks) and tried the solution empty `.htaccess` file and generating it again, but still I am getting same `http://www.example.com/emp/2/` URL.

I guess this problem occurs because I have updated wordpress from 3.3.2 to 3.4

Does anyone have any idea how resolve this?

Comment: please paster your loop in your question... need that to have a look

Comment: Is `%category%%postname%/` a typo? (missing a forward slash)

Answer (score 1):

I guess permalink structure should be

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not clear which URL format you want! As you've set pretty URLs permalink, it will be something like `/emp/category/page-title` (if you've set `%category%/%postname%`) not like `/emp/?page_id=PAGE_ID`. Moreover, the permalink structure that you set is for post. The posts will be shown as `/emp/category/postname` but pages will be shown as `/emp/pagename`. it should not show url like `/emp/2` unless page title is 2.

For detail investigation, please post the permalink structure that you've set in Settings->Permalink section in admin panel and contents of .htaccess that is in `emp` directory as it apparent that you've installed wordpress in `emp` directory.